# What is the meaning of "comparable Dirac and Majorana terms"?

Tags: definition, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

When reading [Mechanism for ordinary-sterile neutrino mixing](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.58.093017?casa_token=QyvDoelPUqEAAAAA%3AO0MkzCGobe7M3gKnp-FNWgnsei6OR6Lm8yx4k9yOQvi95wwbuAo4dU-slq8NhGnnfb5NoMhBhh2zG-g) it is stated in the abstract that:

*"(...)sterile neutrinos can occur only if Dirac and Majorana mass terms exist which are both small and comparable."*

What is the meaning of comparable in this context? Does it means both mass terms must be on a similar scale (energy wise)?

Later in the article the conditions for them to be comparable are given, but it still doesn't say what comparable truly means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference is just fine and clear, and refers you to [2] and [20] if you wish to know more. It discusses its mass matrix (1) mixing active and sterile species.

If $m_D=0$, or $m_M=0$, there is no mixing. If $m_D\ll m_M$ as in the celebrated see-saw scenario, the masses of the eigenstates are huge ($m_M$) and small ($m_D^2/m_M$), respectively, but then the mixing is insignificant, $O(m_D/m_M)$; this is what the author is reminding your to exclude.

So in order to have *nontrivial* sterile neutrinos that matter (~are observable, indirectly: second class oscillations), you need *comparable* mass matrix parameters $m_D$ and $m_M$, i.e. they are comparable numbers, like 1 and 3.7 times a common mass scale. That mass scale must, of course, be small, since we are talking about neutrino masses, and we *know* active neutrino masses are small.

Comment: The concept of comparable was what I was not understanding that last paragraph of yours made it perfectly clear. Thank you.